# GroupBy and Select in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to get a list of all unique combinations of make and model and also include the most recent time stamp and the color from the following table:

```
+-------+---------+-------------------------+--------+
| Make  | Model   |        Last Seen        | Color  |
+-------+---------+-------------------------+--------+
| Volvo | XC90    | 2022-03-11 13:30:31.623 | Blue   |
| Volvo | XC90    | 2022-03-11 14:30:31.623 | Green  |
| BMW   | M3      | 2022-03-11 15:30:31.623 | Orange |
| Ford  | Mustang | 2022-03-11 16:30:31.623 | Red    |
+-------+---------+-------------------------+--------+
```

This query will give me a list of all combinations of make and model and include the latest timestamp, but I don't know how I can also include the Color.

```
    var lastSeen = _context.Cars.GroupBy(o => new {o.Make, o.Model})
        .Select(n => new {Make = n.Key.Make, Model = n.Key.Model, Max = n.Max(a => a.LastSeen)})
        .ToList();
```

I'm looking for the following output:

```
+-------+---------+-------------------------+--------+
| Make  | Model   |        Last Seen        | Color  |
+-------+---------+-------------------------+--------+  
| Volvo | XC90    | 2022-03-11 14:30:31.623 | Green  |
| BMW   | M3      | 2022-03-11 15:30:31.623 | Orange |
| Ford  | Mustang | 2022-03-11 16:30:31.623 | Red    |
+-------+---------+-------------------------+--------+
```

Thanks!

Comment: The results you show group by Color as well. Volvo XC90 appears once for each color. Add `o.Color` in the `GroupBy` key

Comment: Why Green instead of Blue?

Comment: You don't want the Max color, you want to orderbydescending the date and take the First, surely..? Firstly sure EF5+ translates that as a ROW_NUMBER sub query but I'm not sure about earlier EFC. What version do you use?

Comment: Does `context.Cars.GroupBy(o => new {o.Make, o.Model})
        .Select(n => n.OrderByDescending(c => c.LastSeen).First())
        .ToList();` translate?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Sorry for not being precise. I ment that I want to pic whatever color the is in the row with the latest timestamp. Thats why green is chosen over blue

Comment: @CaiusJard Thanks for the suggestion, Im just getting null back from the query though.. Ill try to setup an example in dotnetfiddle.net

Comment: Gotta admit I'm a bit puzzled how ToList can return null

Comment: I tried creating a simple example, and it did not return null, like you suspected. It threw an exception instead. I posted the example in a new question. Would really appreciate if you had the chance to take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71456006/using-groupby-to-pick-rows-in-entity-fraework